# Ubuntu drivers not picking up FTDI Dual RS232-HS

Tags: usb

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on 3 servers. 2 of them properly detect an FTDI Dual RS232-HS chip when connected. The /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyUSB1 paths are created and the devices shows up with lsusb. When I try connecting the chip on the 3rd server, the device doesn't show up in lsusb and the /dev/tty paths aren't created. dmesg shows just the following entry:

```
[158841.032063] usb 5-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
```

What can possibly be causing this? The same chip and cable work on 2 servers but not on another.

Comment: Are the 3 servers identical?  Sounds like a setting in the BIOS perhaps, there used to be issues in older machines with the IOMMU setting.  Try booting into the BIOS and have a look at the USB settings.

Comment: They are identical. They each have Rog Strixx X570-F Gaming motherboards and are 2 years old.